# Meteor filtered publication with limit and skip with total count

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-publications

Given a filtered and paginated meteor publication, how do I get the total count with the filtered applied?

Client Code:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Track } from 'meteor/tracker';

import { Posts } from '/imports/api/posts/posts.js';

import './posts.html';

Template.App_posts.onCreated(function() {
  this.subscribe('posts.all', new Date(), 0);

  Tracker.autorun(() => {
    let postCount = Posts.find({}).count();
    console.log(postCount); // 10
  });
});
```

Server Code:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';

import { Posts } from '../posts.js';

const postsPerPage = 10;

Meteor.publish('posts.all', function(date, page = 0) {
  if (!Meteor.userId()) throw new Meteor.Error('Unauthorised');

  check(date, Date);
  check(page, Number);

  let query = {
    userId: Meteor.userId()
  };

  let options = {};

  if (date) {
    query.createdAt = date;
  }

  options.limit = postsPerPage;
  options.skip = page * postsPerPage;

  let cursor = Posts.find(query, options);

  console.log(cursor.count()); // 100

  return cursor;
});
```

This returns the expected posts given the date and the page but the problem is knowing the total filtered count.

Assuming there is 1000 posts, 100 of them are applicable for this date and user. How do I get the count of 100 when only 10 are returned at a time?

Comment: BTW I think "if (!Meteor.userId()) throw new Meteor.Error('Unauthorised');" is not a good idea cause, in this case, publish on the client will never be ready. More info here https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html

Comment: Thanks but in my use case the subscription is for logged in users only and the publication is not used on any logged out screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use tmeasday:publish-counts  https://github.com/percolatestudio/publish-counts

On the server, you should do:

```
Meteor.publish('posts.numberOfPosts', function(date) {
   if (!this.userId){
       return this.ready();
   } 
   check(date, Date);

   let query = {
      userId: this.userId
   };
   if (date) {
     query.createdAt = date;
   }
   Counts.publish(this, 'all-posts', Posts.find(query));
}
```

And on the client: 
Counts.get('All-orders')

Actually, you also may place this subscription inside "posts.all":

```
Meteor.publish('posts.all', function(date, page = 0) {
  if (!Meteor.userId()) throw new Meteor.Error('Unauthorised');

  check(date, Date);
  check(page, Number);

  let query = {
    userId: Meteor.userId()
  };

  let options = {};

  if (date) {
    query.createdAt = date;
  }

  options.limit = postsPerPage;
  options.skip = page * postsPerPage;

  let cursor = Posts.find(query, options);
  // https://github.com/percolatestudio/publish-counts#noready
  Counts.publish(this, 'all-posts', Posts.find(query), {noReady: true});

  return cursor;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have looked into that package already and it states that it has performance issues with large datasets. I was also hoping to have it all wrapped up in one publication if that is even possible?

Comment: I've updated my answer, yes you can do it inside one publication.

Comment: Hi Ivan, I see now thanks for that. Do you have any experience with meteor-publish-performant-counts? As this package claims to be more performant than publish-counts. I have tried to use this package in the same way as above with no luck.

Comment: Not really, but I think for this package you need be used in a separate subscription

Comment: You can also try your luck with https://atmospherejs.com/ros/publish-counts it claims to be more perfomant

Comment: And also you can simple write meteor method and call it from your client code - it won't be reactive, but it will work pretty fast

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestions. I'll mark this correct as it does answer my question but I will need to find a more performance solution preferably with one subscription.

Comment: I think the only “performant” way with large data sets is to keep the count on every post document and increment with each new insertion and you only publish/subscribe for the last document (post.count).  I understand you need the count of all posts not a count of particular posts so incrementing a number on either the post object or something like a states/count collection would serve you far better on long run. Count of all post is not something I would subscribe to because it is not worth it particularly because design wise it is wrong. This is why Meteor apps “become sluggish over time”.

Comment: Hi Paul, the query is actually alot more complicated than the example and thus is a subset of the collection. Therefore maintaining the count in the collection is not viable for my use case.